# How to locate the file node in the sidebar of current opened file, in sublime?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

I'm using sublime to open a directory, and viewing a file now. Is there any keyshort to let me locate the file in the sidebar?

[image]

You can see I'm view `rythm.dart` file, how to locate it in the left file tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please install side bar plugins.
and Reveal in side bar in the right click.